# Вопросы по действиям, которые могут нарушать закон

Tags: обсуждение, правила, тематика

Наткнулся на [следующий текст вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443214/181472):

> На одном ресурсе нашел флешку, декомпилировать получилось, есть полный исходный код. Хочу сделать идентичное работающее приложение у себя, вопрос...

... в настоящий момент закрывается с формулировкой:

> Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что декомпиляция чужих продуктов, не есть хорошо.

На мой взгляд, «не есть хорошо» это довольно слабая аргументация для закрытия вопроса. Не есть — хорошо, есть — плохо, кашу — тем более. Как это относится к тематике SO?

**Вопрос: допустимы ли на StackOverflow на русском вопросы, касающиеся действий, которые могут нарушать закон?**

- Поскольку в разных странах законы различаются, по каким мы будем ориентироваться? Или будем опираться на некий «здравый смысл»?
- Как можно, и можно ли вынести однозначное суждение по поводу намерений автора вопроса? Вправе ли пользователи выносить такое суждение?
- Кто и какие меры должен предпринимать в отношении такого содержимого?
- Очень часто можно сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы не раскрывать факт нарушения закона. Можно было бы просто сказать «у меня есть код, помогите понять вот этот участок». Но если мы уже знаем, что автор что-то нарушил, можем ли мы рекомендовать правку, которая скроет этот факт?

Предлагаю здесь обсуждать аргументацию и критерии «можно» / «нельзя». Если дискуссия приведет к необходимости изменения раздела справки, будет создан отдельный [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

На всякий случай: проблема плагиата в сообщениях, описаниях меток и других документах к этому вопросу не относится. Плагиат это не сообщение о нарушении, а нарушение с помощью сообщения.

Answer (score 11):

Декомпиляция может быть законной. Почти любое действие может быть законным. Всё что угодно может быть сделано чисто из любопытства "а как это".

Например на Хабре есть статья, где учат декомпилировать программу на примере какого-то кейгена. Это поясняется тем, что кейгены не защищены законом, а без знания того, для какой программы он сделан, информация о полученном алгоритме генерации ключа бесполезна.

За законностью своих действий должен следить сам автор, а не отвечающие.

Comment: Можно ссылку на статью, слишком сомнительно выглядит утверждение, что на кейгены не распространяется защита законов.

Answer (score 5):

> **Поскольку в разных странах законы различаются, по каким мы будем ориентироваться?**

Ни по каким, т.к. есть [пользовательское соглашение](http://stackexchange.com/legal), раздел 4:

> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited.

Из этого следует, что участник SO не вправе спрашивать здесь о том, как ему воспользоваться декомпилированным проприетарным кодом. Но совершенно не следует, что другие участники должны или могут заниматься предотвращением нарушений. Да, у нас есть система модерации, но она добровольная. К тому же пункта «Нелегальное содержимое» в ней на данный момент нет.

> **Как можно, и можно ли вынести однозначное суждение по поводу намерений автора вопроса? Вправе ли пользователи выносить такое суждение?**

Я могу подозревать нарушение, но не хотел бы брать ответственность за принятие решения о том, был ли нарушен закон и/или пользовательское соглашение. Все-таки я не юрист и эти вопросы вне моей компетенции. Это сложнее, чем определение спама.

Считаю, что пока возможность сообщать о возможных нарушениях не выделена отдельным пунктом в меню «тревог», **следует использовать «привлечь внимание модератора» с сообщением «вопрос о действиях, нарушающих закон».**

Comment: С другой стороны, реверс--инжениринг кода может быть и вполне легальным — например, как часть обучения эксперта по безопасности. Или как анализ ошибки кодогенерации (много примеров на en.SO). Поэтому, как мне кажется, просьба разобраться с куском декомпилированного кода **сама по себе** не должна восприниматься как следствие противоправных действий.

Comment: @VladD: Согласен. В том и проблема наша, что мы не можем вынести обоснованное суждение о легальности только по тому факту, что код декомпилирован.

Comment: Согласен с @VladD, мне, например, в свое время было крайне интересно разобраться с [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/). Обычно "кулл хацкеров" видно за километр, так как качество их вопросов крайне плохо, а сами вопросы быстро удаляются. В общем, я бы удалял все, что относится к "взлому вконтакте" как спам, а более сложные, но нарушающие закон вопросы, как не относящиеся к тематике или всеобъемлющие, так как если бы вопрос был задан конкретно, сообщество бы не догадалось, что с вопросом что-то не так.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Мне кажется, «взлом вконтакте» стоит удалять как «вопрос, направленный на открытое и очевидное причинение вреда».

Comment: На сайте такой вопрос можно отметить только как спам (коим он в конечном счете и является).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Спамом было бы «взломаю вконтакте за вознаграждение» (навязчивая реклама). А вот «подскажите, как бы мне взломать сайт Х», как мне кажется, рекламой не является. Но это, разумеется, неэтичный вопрос.

Comment: @VladD: вот отличный вариант ответа на такой вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/51597/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это тот самый случай, когда хороший ответ спасает плохой вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Которые нарушают закон? Т.е. должно быть доказательство того что оно нарушает закон. Иначе любое сообщение можно подвести под данную категорию, ведь почти все можно использовать для нарушения закона. И если позволить модераторам решать что хотели использовать для нарушения закона, а что нет, это ведь приведет к произволу и закрытию вопросов просто потому что настроение у модератора плохое.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Что считаю и произошло с моим вопросом - ведь там некуда больше уточнять, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0  Потому предлагаю считать пользователей добросовестными если не можешь доказать обратного, и не закрывать их вопросы в таком случае.

Comment: @Hertz Николас уже не администратор, и комментарии к древним вопросам никто не проверяет, поэтому здесь писать бесполезно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Идею того, что не стоит закрывать вопросы основываясь на мнении модератора о намерении задающего вопрос, высказал, не преследуя цели повлиять на судьбу моего вопроса про майнер, а для того чтобы поучаствовать в обсуждении. Но спс за уточнение.