# Обсуждение написания вирусов

Tags: обсуждение

На SO нельзя задавать вопросы о написании вирусов?

Где задать вопрос по созданию клавиатурного шпиона?

Comment: у фрилансеров поспрашивайте

Comment: Задавайте не о шпионе вопрос, а перехвате событий нажатия в языке %вставь_название% или подобное.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Клавиатурный шпион совсем не обязательно является вирусом (PuntoSwitcher, всяческие дневники и т. д.), поэтому о его написании вопрос на ruSO задавать можно.

Когда такой вопрос обсуждался, было принято решение, что автор вопроса несёт ответственность за способ использования полученных сведений.

- [Вопросы по действиям, которые могут нарушать закон](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1070/178988)
- [Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/178988)

Однако, конечно, спрашивать, как написать вирус, не стоит.

Comment: Не стоит. Заминусуют ))