# Насколько применим принцип «не навреди»?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, тематика

Вопрос этического плана. Вызван следующим: на ruSO появился вопрос, в котором его автор интересуется программными механизмами поломки железной части компьютера (буквально «как бы мне спалить блок питания?»). Я так понимаю, что здесь почему-то не принято указывать на участников прямо, так что, скажем, один из уважаемых участников проголосовал за закрытие этого вопроса, исходя из принципа «не навреди».

Отсюда вопрос: как быть с этим принципом? Имеет ли он приоритет над принципом «предполагайте добрые намерения?» Должна ли для него быть отдельная причина закрытия?

К вопросу о приоритете: вообще-то вопросов, имеющих двойное назначение, немало. Вот прямо в момент написания на главной висит вопрос об оптимизации перебора приватных ключей для поиска по данному BTC-адресу. Вопросу четыре месяца. Предполагать для него добрые намерения? Или лучше «не навредить»?

Если я заново заезжаю на давным-давно обсуждённую тему, наверное, в качестве ответа достаточно будет ссылки на предыдущие обсуждения.

Comment: Ломать железо законом не запрещено (а иногда и [по закону обязательно](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_61801/4f41fe599ce341751e4e34dc50a4b676674c1416/#p63)), так что а не пофиг ли?

Comment: Ой ли? Ст. 167 УК РФ, например.

Comment: Блок питания чужой? Его планируется спалить общеопасным способом? Если нет — тогда при чём тут ст. 167 УК РФ?

Comment: @andreymal Весьма вероятно, что чужой, и весьма вероятно, что было бы повреждено имущество (то есть нарушена работа компьютера) дороже, чем 5 тысяч рублей (только сам БП, который вообще предполагается к уничтожению, может на 5 тысяч потянуть). То есть в значительном размере.

Comment: Весьма вероятно, что вы сейчас возьмёте нож на своей кухне и зарежете вашего соседа. Давайте посадим вас за убийство, пока не стало слишком поздно? ;)

Comment: Ну и да, обязательно запретить любую информацию в интернете про заточку ножей, а магазины с ножами закрыть, а то мало ли чего, знаете ли.

Comment: @andreymal ну очевидно же плохой пример. Потому что я не интересуюсь здесь вопросами попадания ножом в жизненно важные органы.

Comment: Такой же плохой, как и ваш. Поэтому предлагаю вам завязывать с демагогией вида «весьма вероятно».

Comment: И кстати *весьма вероятно*, что вы *скрываете* свой интерес к ножам и их нецелевому использованию.

Comment: @andreymal то есть по поводу "значительного размера" возражений не имеется.

Comment: Пусть он стоит хоть триллион американских долларов — если он свой и уничтожается не общеопасным способом (или на закрытом полигоне) — это абсолютно законно, и писать об этом в базах знаний никем не запрещено (при условии соответствия тематике, конечно).

Comment: Считаю, что это дубликат прошлого обсуждения, так как вопрос именно о ***программном*** механизме поломки. Я бы отнёс такие уязвимости к разновидности DoS-атак.

Comment: @andreymal Демагогия в данном случае это твой аргумент про нож. Для ножа есть куча способов, как применить его с пользой, а для "спалить блок питания" какие? Кроме того, ножи и их применение вообще не имеет никакого отношения к тематике сайта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight изучить слабые места защиты программ/железа, чтобы усилить их, конечно же. Узнать, как делать не надо, чтобы не спалить просто случайно, разумеется. То же самое касается всех "взломов".

Answer (score 9):

Конкретно про вопросы о поломке железа обсуждений не помню, но, к примеру, было обсуждение [вопросов про взломы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/15479). И, в общем-то, решили, что [таким вопросам быть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/15479).

Недопустимы лишь вопросы, которые [нарушают закон](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1070/15479). Скажем, вопросы из разряда "как взломать чей-то аккаунт в VK" и т.п. А вопросы про реверс инженеринг и декомпиляцию допустимы.

По поводу "как спалить блок питания" не уверен, нужно смотреть на вопрос. Но, мне видится, что ситуация схожа.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d0%9e

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev сложно. Возможно стоит тогда вопрос ваш переформулировать во что-то вроде "Что делать с вопросами про вывод из строя железа?", чтоб сузить обсуждение.

Comment: Не-не, вопрос довольно сознательно сформулирован в виде противопоставления очень общих принципов. Мне интересны мнения людей, потому что "не навреди" легко переходит в подход "а не _может_ ли это быть использовано для целей, которые мне видятся дурными?", а "предполагать добрые намерения" — в "ну разве ж я знал, что если он сверлит ствол, то он из него по людям стрелять будет?" Первое — охранительство, второе — попустительство. Что хуже и как найти баланс — я не знаю, поэтому вот потащил на обсуждение.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev логично. Посмотрим, что другие скажут. Хорошо быть Harry в это обсуждение позвать)

Comment: Заглянет когда-нибудь, надеюсь. Не спешим же.