# Предвзятое отношение - можно ли дискриминировать отдельную технологию?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, переоткрытие-вопросов

Задал вопрос про js майнинг: [Как сделать майнер для сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561962/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

И суть вопроса предельна проста - помогите найти/написать самому скрипт соответствующий определенным критериям, таких вопросов куча на RU SO. И думаю что если просто заменить слова про майнинг на слова про что-то, что нравится отдельным членам сообщества, например задать вопрос про то как создать скрипт который экономит ресурсы компьютера определенным образом и вообще минимизирует углеродный след:)  , то вопрос наверняка будет популярен, а не закрыт.

В связи с чем хочется поставить вопрос о т.н. Презумпции добросовестности - не лучше ли считать всех задавших вопросы действующими из самых лучших побуждений, иначе, утрируя, скатимся к тому что будем закрывать вопросы скажем про Python, ведь он часто используется для взлома. Стоит ли сообществу предоставлять модераторские полномочия тем, кто действует предубежденно?

Что конкретно следует сделать чтобы вопрос открыли?

Comment: [Вопросы по действиям, которые могут нарушать закон](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070) / [Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868)

Comment: В обсуждении по ссылке пришли к тому что нельзя удалять вопросы которые лишь предположительно причиняют вред. А мой вопрос четко указывает что майнинг будет вестись с согласия пользователя, а майнинг законен. И потому думаю что вопрос в личном отношении, а не в законности.

Comment: Нужен скрипт - это на фриланс биржу. А ресурс тут совсем об ином

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Найти готовое решение или получить представление о том как это работает чтобы написать самому.   С таким успехом можно отправить на фриланс того кто спрашивает как установить что-то или как работает какая-то функция - пускай идет на фриланс и ему там это сделают. Предлагаю в поиск вбить "Нужен скрипт" и почитать сколько таких вопросов вполне хорошо себя чувствуют.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Готов уточнить данный момент если дело только в этом- типо: не нужно за меня писать, а расскажите пож. как это сделать и есть ли готовое решение.

Comment: Поиск готовых решений - не тут. Как это сделать - слишком общий вопрос. Нужна конкретика. Что делал, что пытался, с какими трудностями столкнулся. Зависает скрипт и нужно улучшить производительность - показывай что есть и пиши что не так... А все эти поиски готовых решений - это в другом месте

Comment: Поставил минус просто потому что тут перемешано 4 разных вопроса. В заголовке одно, в теле второе и третье, в эпилоге - четвертое. Отдельно отмечу - *"И суть вопроса предельна проста - помогите найти ..."* - так вопрос или просьба найти за вас готовое решение?

Comment: @Kromster Исправил про поиск скрипта. Предполагаю что не с качеством вопроса связано закрытие и потому вытекает второе и третье.

Comment: @Hertz, к сожалению, вы тут уже ничего добиться не сможете, похоже наш сайт приближается к концу...

Comment: @avp Иронизируете? Или в чем, по вашему причина "приближения к концу", и так ли он неизбежен?

Comment: @Hertz, рад бы, но нет. Причина же, imho, в том, что заорганизованность растет, обсуждать что-то интересное в вопросах-ответах-комментариях новые люди и не пытаются (я уже давно забросил подобные попытки...). И как вы думаете, когда, вот вам, например, надоест просто отвечать на одни и те же вопросы? Вот люди и уходят.

Answer (score 6):

*Я не участвовал в закрытии вопроса и только что впервые увидел ваш вопрос здесь и на основном сайте.*

Ваш вопрос звучит как "Как майнить крипту незаметно для пользователя". Такие темы здесь не принято обсуждать, а тем более - отвечать.

Далее, вопрос общий. Суть майнинга сводится к подсчету хэшей. Хэш не можете посчитать? Нагрузку снизить? Данные передать для учета на базу или что конкретно? Вопрос следовало разбить на детали и задавать про что-то конкретное, при этом очень желательно постараться написать какой-то код перед тем как задать вопрос, чтобы было что обсуждать.

Возможно причина закрытия "невозможно дать объективный ответ", но я бы определённо закрыл с другой причиной - "нужно конкретизировать". Попробуйте переосмыслить свою задачу, декомпозировать и решать поэтапно.

Алгоритмы подсчёта хэшей есть в открытом доступе, есть готовые библиотеки. Для снижения нагрузки в JS есть асинхронное программирование, и так далее. Главное - иметь конкретную задачу, тогда и решение быстрее придёт.

Не стоит винить сообщество в том, что оно отказалось искать полноценное решение на комплексный вопрос. Здесь вопросы такого типа крайне редко получают ответы, ничего экстраординарного в реакции сообщества на ваш вопрос я не нашёл.

Начните с простого - попробуйте посчитать один единственный хэш и получить результат в нужном формате.

[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "с возможностью настройки пользователем нагрузки на его компьютер" - это, говорит о том что пользователь будет сам настраивать нагрузку, а значит непременно знать о майнинге.

Comment: @Hertz я разве сказал, что закрыл бы вопрос, потому что он неэтичен? Нет, я такого не говорил.

Comment: Вы написали "Ваш вопрос звучит как "Как майнить крипту незаметно для пользователя", а я указываю что он так не звучит потому что пользователю известно о майнинге.  И скажем если бы был задан вопрос о том как встроить видео в сайт, то никаких проблем не возникло бы, человеку рассказали бы про то что видео встраивается с помощью плеера, прислали бы ссылки на html5 плеер и еще пару чтобы мог попробовать. Никто не стал бы говорить о том как работают кодеки, hls, mp4 и прочее. Но если вопрос о том как встроить майнинг он слишком общий. Помогите пож. прочувствовать разницу.

Comment: Вы ответ поняли или нет?

Comment: Вы читали мой вопрос со сравнением чуть выше или нет? Никто не спускается на уровень обсуждения того как устроены примитивные конструкции процесса когда человек спрашивает как обрабатывать видео или как перемножить два числа. Человеку дают функцию или библиотеку. И ответ в виде: вот библиотека которая майнит или ее легко написать по следующему алгоритму..., а с помощью CURL можно из API пула получить статистику потому мне кажется разумным ответом, а заявление о общем характере вопроса надуманным. Я не закусил удила, а реально разобраться хочу если что.

Comment: Если считать заплюсованные решения на мете за правила, поиск готовых скриптов должен быть разрешен: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9491/240512 Интересный пример, как разрешение всего подряд может иметь плохие последствия, ибо автор не только некачественный вопрос притащил, но и еще права качает, типа другим скрипты дают, а мне нет...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight никто не запрещает искать библиотеки. Автор спрашивает как майнить неизвестную крипту в неизвестном браузере и просит методику снижения нагрузки на устройство для несуществующего решения. Хоть-бы указал, какую крипту надо и на какие платформы. Wasm катит или нет, и т.д. Ну а потом этическая сторона вопроса не решается обещаниями не шалить. Вопросы типа "помогите написать вирус для курсовой работы в исключительно безобидных целях" не являются безобидными, так как даже если автор честный, другой посетитель может взять этот же ответ и использовать как решение для вредоноса.

Comment: @Hertz попробуйте сформулировать вопрос более явно следуя рекомендациям из справки, возможно ситуация с оценкой качества вопроса поменяется.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А может дело в том что из личных предпочтений жмут участников, минусуют не указывая проблемы а когда взывает к справедливости участник, вместо аргументов, про него говорят что он "права качает". Где микрополнамочия, там мегодиктат - синдром вахтера фарева. И я не первый кто про это говорит - вон на Мете про это сколько. Вопрос несколькими коментами выше - но нет, ответить никто не удосужится, зато бесплодно повторять желающих навалом.

Comment: @aepot Да, я переделаю, а лучше оставлю чтобы пример был. Задать вопрос не критично. Критично что такая реакция на данный вопрос. Сами признаете что дело в морали. Сколько из 10-и минусов, по вашему связано с плохой формулировкой вопроса, а сколько с тем что он про, потенциально неэтичное ПО.  Предлагаю инкогнито создать такой-же вопрос но заменить "js майнер" на, скажем "генератор голоса по тексту". И посмотреть сколько будет рейтинг и закроют ли его - думается что нет.

Comment: @Hertz у вас не только этическая, а полный букет причин вопрос прикрыть и заминусовать. Надеюсь, я прояснил хоть немного ситуацию. Вряд-ли ещё что-либо смогу добавить к уже выданным рекомендациям.

Comment: @aepot И согласен с тем что может прийти другой человек который использует вирус/майнер неэтично. Но так-ведь почти любой скрипт можно использовать неэтично/незаконно. И, думается нужна эта граница., как для потенциально неэтичных скриптов, так и для того что считать широким вопросом.

Comment: @aepot Скажем если просит рассказать как перемножить два числа на python ему не говорили что вопрос широкий и это можно сделать несколькими способами - т.е. ширина вопроса зависит от глубины на которую хочет вникнуть отвечающий. И тот, кто занимался всю жизнь оптимизацией вероятно расскажет 10 способов перемножения для разных ситуаций. Но, тот кто задает вопрос и не думает о том что это широкая тема, ему хоть что-то попробовать для старта. Надеюсь вы уловили таки этот смысл.